# Getting columns to go bottom of page with fixed footer

Tags: html, css

I am currently lost as to how to proceed with my problem. I have a two column layout, with a fixed header and footer. I want the columns in the body to go all the way to the bottom of the page, I've been playing around with 100% heights, JS, etc, but I cant seem to get anything to work. My code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
    <!--CSS Styling-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/basic.css">

</head>

<body>
    <!-- Header-->
    <header>
        <div id="header-container">

            <!-- Hidden heading for outline -->
            <h1>Main Title </h1>

            <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/header-logo.jpg" alt="header-logo" width="220" height="50"/></a>

            <nav class="clearFix">

                <ol>
                    <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>    
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tips.html">Tips</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a></li>
                 </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!--Main-->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <main class="gridSystem clearFix"> 

            <section class="grid" id="home">
                <h1>Welcome to Site</h1>

                <img  class="headshot" src="Images/headshot.jpg" alt="brittany-headshot" width="300" height="300"/>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
            </section>



            <section class="grid" id="home-services">
                <h2>Services Offered</h2>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>

                <ul>
                    <li>Item1</li>
                    <li>Item2</li>
                    <li>Item3</li>
                    <li>Item4</li>
                    <li>Item5</li>
                </ul>
            </section>

        </main>
    </div>
    <footer><p>Copyright | &copy; 2014 </p></footer>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{border: none;
margin: 0;
padding:0;}

body{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: #828282;
}

#wrapper{
position: relative;
top: 65px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 940px;
background-color: #828282;
height:100%;
}

/* Header*/
header{
height: 60px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000000;
margin: 0px;
border-bottom: 5px solid #f0f0f0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 5;
}
#header-container{
width:940px;
height: 50px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
header img{
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 5px;
float:left;
}
header h1{
display: none;
}

/* Navigation */
nav{    
float:left;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: 0px;
font-size: 18px;
color: black;
font-weight: 300;
}

nav li{
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
margin: 0;
background-color: #424242;
margin-left: 15px;

}
nav li:first-child{
margin-left: 20px;
}   

nav ol {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

nav a {text-decoration: none;
margin: 0;
}

/*General Styling*/
h1{
font-size: 30px;
}

h1,h2,h3,p{
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
ul{
margin:0px 20px;
}
a:link {color:#999999;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color: #999999;}
a:hover {color:#FFFFFF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#FFFFFF;}  /* selected link */

/*--index.html--*/
.grid{
display:block;
margin: 0px 20px 20px 0;
padding: 20px;
float: left;
}
#home{
width: 580px;
background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
#home-services{
width: 260px;
background-color: #c0c0c0;
margin: 0;
}
.headshot{
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*--grid--*/
.gridSystem{
margin-right:  -20px;

}
/* -- footer --*/
footer p {font-size: 10px;  
color:#f0f0f0;
text-align: center;
line-height: 30px;
}
footer {border-top: 5px solid #f0f0f0;
height: 30px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000000;
color: #ffffff;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
}

/*--ClearFix--*/
.clearFix:after {
clear: both;
display: table;
content: "";
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Can anyone possibly lend me a hand here? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want actually. The left column is already on the right place, right? And the right one has to be aligned to the bottom instead of left?

Comment: on larger resolutions, I need both columns to go to the bottom of the page. The left column ends about half way up on larger resolution monitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure that i understand what you are looking for here but i have created a fiddle with what i assume you want

http://jsfiddle.net/wvZqr/

I have added a min-height to your .grid class to make both columns equal in height

```
.grid {
display: block;
margin: 0px 20px 20px 0;
padding: 20px;
float: left;
min-height: 620px;
}
```

Here is the JS method to accomplish this

You will need to include jQuery any version should do, and then the script tag below

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function(){
        var grid = $(window).height();
        var gridFinal = grid - 85;
        $('.grid').css({'min-height': ((gridFinal))+'px'});
    });

</script>
```

For the 85 i am calculating this based on your header being 50px height and your footer of 35 giving the total of 85 is that changes just change the 85 to whatever the new combined height is between header and footer

Comment: Basically I am looking to make both columns 100%, so no matter what, each columm goes to the bottom of the page/footer.

Comment: Is there a reason why this works with a pixel value, but when I switch to 100%, it doesn't work?

Comment: This is a pretty good article explaining why height % is a bad idea... http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm

If you found my answer correct please mark it with the check mark as accepted.

Comment: I can see what you mean, but I'm still unsure as to how the columns will be able to adjust to the bottom of the page if someone is using a high resolution, do you get what I mean?

Comment: Ohhhh i do now see what you mean by this, would JS be an option to take care of this?

Comment: I would happily put osme JS in there if it exists, I just don't know enough about JS to even know where to start with this.

Comment: I have edited my answer above to include the way to do this with JS. it is pretty straight forward but if you have any questions let me know.

Comment: Hey, @Travis , I just filled everything in with content, works great, except for two pages that are not sizing correctly. I just temporarily uploaded to sweb2.dmit.nait.ca/kerickson16/prototype/ .. would you mind looking at the about page and the tips page? I cant figure out what's happening. The about page I assume it's because of my images but the tips, I have no idea.

Comment: It looks like you have gotten this resolved? i dont see anything that looks off currently?